# Best way to send complex data object to controller via ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send a complex object from my view (via Ajax) to my controller. I know that I can do something like:

```
JSON.stringify(myComplexObject);
```

and then retrieve values in the controller. But is this really the best way to do it? I'm thinking some sort of data contract between view and controller would be better?

Comment: Make a ApiController and use that one for JSON communication between client & server

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController",FormMethod.Post))
{
 ....
}

<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                       alert('Ok');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and in your Controller

```
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model)
{
}
```

hope this will help you